# Flask and JQuery - Safari won't register any action made by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask

I am attempting to use flask as a backend for running database queries/updates. I was able to get flask and html playing nicely together, but in order to make the webpage responsive I am trying to use jQuery to perform web interactions.

Here is my simple html file, home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flowers</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="{{url_for('static', filename='javascript/eventManager.js')}}"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="demo"> Flowers</h1>
    <h2>List of Flowers</h2>

    {% if data %}
    {% for item in data %}
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td>{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        <p>Didn't work</p>
      {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my test jQuery script, eventManager.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("My First Jquery Test");
});
```

And here is the file structure for my project

[Project File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtSmG.png)

I have tried using this as suggested by others in place of document, but it also did not work

```
jQuery(window).loadfunction() {
     alert("My First Jquery Test");
});
```

The alert (or any other jQuery function) works in Chrome. It also worked in safari when put inline with the html.

Comment: Do you have any error in the console? Also you don't need `$(function(){})` since you're have the document ready function.

Comment: No error is produced in the console. And thanks, I will edit that.

Comment: Check the _Network_ tab of your browser's developer tools — is `eventManager.js` actually being loaded?  Your line `<script type="text/javascript"src="{{url_for(...` has no space between _type_ and _src_ - could be a paste error here? but the browser may not like it and not load the file.

Comment: This helped me determine the issue. Thank you. Safari wasn't updating my javascript file. I didn't rename it with versions and I was using the cache even while developing. I turned off "using the resource cache while developing" and now it updates. What a headache.